# Hidden divs at the end of the document

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I've noticed that, since I've included Slimbox - lightbox on my site, there are some hidden divs at the end of the document.

`<div id="lbOverlay" style="opacity: 0.8; display: none;"></div>
<div id="lbCenter" class="" style="top: 2094.5px; width: 620px; height: 764px; margin-left: -310px; left: 951.5px; display: none;">
<div id="lbBottomContainer" style="left: 951.5px; width: 620px; top: 2858.5px; margin-left: -310px; display: none;">`

I realize they are from slimbox itself, but I would like to know is there any way to have a "clean code" ie, without them at the end of document.

Comment: I think that's how the lightbox works, this isn't uncommon and you don't need to worry about it

Comment: People aren't going to be looking at the code, they don't care how "clean" it is. They care about whether the lightbox works to show them the info they want. Let lightbox put whatever hidden divs it wants into the code. Tons of javascript plugins do this, there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to avoid this is to use another lightbox plugin. You could reverse engineer Slimbox to remove them automatically; but then, why reinvent the wheel?

However, be advised that they're probably not cleaned up from the DOM to help performance. I wouldn't worry about them.

Comment: I was wondering what I did wrong, because
I came across couple of sites which had some sort of lightbox (if not the same), but didn't have those divs at the end of document, so I assumed I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with BenM! I assume that you are asking for "clean" code because of the inline style's but that is just how JS interacts with the DOM. You would need to create a class for the style that they are creating and change the Lightbox plugin to use those classes but a lot of times those top and left's are dynamically generated based on the end users screen resolution.